# Adding Buttons to a JPanel with an existing Button in GUI

Tags: java, swing, button, jpanel, actionlistener

I am trying to program my first own Java Application and I want to create  a buttons into the GUI. Here is the program I want to run.

If I click on an existing button in the GUI. I would be adding an `ActionListener` but I just want add a Button only. If I click both Buttons in my GUI. First run `LoadProgress` then `Hinzufügen`. How can I fix it so that I create a Button only if I click on the `Hinzufügen` Button.

```
private void pnlLeft(){
   JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar();
   bar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 30));
   getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, bar);

   JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
   panel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel2, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

   JButton btnLoad = new JButton("LoadProgress");
   JButton leftbutton = new JButton("Hinzufügen");
   panel2.add(leftbutton);
   panel2.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
   panel2.add(btnLoad);
   getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, panel2);
      leftbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {   
         if(arg0.getActionCommand().equals("Hinzufügen")) { 
            JButton test = new JButton("TEST");
            panel2.add(test);
         }
      }
   });

   btnLoad.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      new Thread() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            if(e.getActionCommand().equals("LoadProgress")) {   
               bar.setStringPainted(true);
               for ( int f = 1; f <= 100; f++) {
                  try {
                     Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 100));
                  }catch (InterruptedException ex){
                     ex.printStackTrace();
                  } 
                  bar.setString("Lade Bestand..." + f + "%");
                  bar.setValue(f);
               }
               bar.setValue(0);
               bar.setStringPainted(false);     
            }
         }
      }.start();
   }});
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add (or remove) a component from a visible GUI the basic code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate(); // invokes layout manager
panel.repaint();
```

Otherwise the component has a default size of (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

Comment: thank you very much. It worked. I just wrote it under the panel.add(test).